# AddOrUpdate syntax using EF & SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm using an `AddOrUpdate` method to update table entry.

I've tried this code:

```
_db.Cars.AddOrUpdate(car => car.Id == Id, new Car()
                                              {
                                                   CarBrand = ViewModel.Brand,
                                                   CarModel = ViewModel.Model,
                                                   CarNumber = ViewModel.Number,
                                                   EngType = ViewModel.EngType
                                              });
```

By using this I get an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException.
> The properties expression `car => Convert((car.Id == value(CarService.Windows.AddCarWindow).Car.Id))` is not valid. The expression should represent a property: `t => t.MyProperty`. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: `t => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }`.

I need help composing the expression.

Car class:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CarBrand { get; set; }
    public string CarModel { get; set; }
    public string CarNumber { get; set; }
    public string EngType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the Id of the car you wish to maybe update, just set it in the Car and let EF sort it out (EF [should, if configured it correctly] know the Id property is the key)

```
_db.Cars.AddOrUpdate(new Car()
{
    Id = ID_YOU_WANT_TO_UPSERT,
    CarBrand = ViewModel.Brand,
    CarModel = ViewModel.Model,
    CarNumber = ViewModel.Number,
    EngType = ViewModel.EngType
});
```

EF will query the db for the Id you supply. If found, an update is applied. If not found, an insert is done. Note; if you do not specify every single property, any unspecified property is set to null on the db side, rather than ignored..

---

In terms of the error you're getting, the first argument to the overload you're using is not supposed to specify a predicate that identifies the object to update, it's supposed to list which properties shall be used in a predicate created by EF to determine equality. For example if you don't know the ID and CarNumber is unique you could add or update based on the CarNumber by:

```
_db.Cars.AddOrUpdate(car => car.CarNumber, new Car()
{
    CarBrand = ViewModel.Brand,
    CarModel = ViewModel.Model,
    CarNumber = ViewModel.Number,
    EngType = ViewModel.EngType
});
```

EF will look for an existing object based on the column you gave in the first argument `car=>car.CarNumber` and the value you gave in the second argument (`ViewModel.CarNumber`) - it will construct the `WHERE CarNumber = 1234` from these

---

AddOrUpdate, AIUI, is no longer a thing - [update can upsert in most common scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didn't help, I've got same exception. And this property not unspcified, Id is 0 by default.

Comment: If you got the same exception then nothing changed. What does your code look like after you changed it?

Comment: I've set Id value of new Car, as you sayed. The exception was in syntax, not in values. In the second part of code, that you're offered, I've tryed, and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Checked the first solution that you offered (after your edit) and it worked too!

Comment: Awesome.. take note of the very last bit though- careful with AddOrUpdate because I'm not sure it exists any more so if you write a bunch of code using it you'll have a bunch more code to write if you upgrade your EF